# Showing MOSS web part in Java based web site

Tags: 2007

Is there any way to show a SharePoint 2007 web part on a web page in a Java web site?

Answer (score 1):

You can create a site page in SharePoint that has nothing but the web part on it (you may have to strip out the page header in the code or hide it with jQuery).  Then on your Java site use an iFrame or a page viewer portlet that shells out to the SharePoint site page.  You may run into authentication issues depending on how your security is set up.

Comment: Thanks Rob, I has suggested the same to my client, but sees he is looking for some possibilities.